# mysql select query display in php

Tags: php, database, select, mysqli

I have a table named: 'paper' (question_bank)

```
            id  |  exam_id | question

            1   |  1       | What will be 35*9?
            2   |  1       | What will be 5-9?
            3   |  1       | A + B
            4   |  1       | What is a circle?
            5   |  1       | If we have four corners with equal height and width, then which shape is that?
            6   |  1       | What is Maths?
            7   |  1       | What is a triangle?
            21  |  1       | what is Nikhil surname?
            22  |  2       | Last name of Bhavesh is
            23  |  2       | Last name of Harsh is
            27  |  3       | What is Maths?
            28  |  3       | What is a triangle?
            30  |  3       | Last name of Harsh is
```

I have a php page where i have to add questions in exam_id '3' from table 'paper'. my query to insert question is as below:

```
INSERT INTO paper (question exam_id) SELECT question, '3' FROM paper WHERE id = '2'
                        OR
INSERT INTO paper (question exam_id) SELECT question, '3' FROM paper WHERE id = '1'
                        OR
```

I can also add a new question, so the query is:

```
INSERT INTO paper (question, exam_id) VALUES ('blah blah blah', '3')
```

It depends on question i select OR any new question i add.

Now, when i want to add more questions to exam_id '3' from table 'paper', it shows all the questions. My select query is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM paper WHERE exam_id != '3'
```

It shows all questions, but for instance i already added id = '23', so i dont want that question to display when i am adding more questions. Please help me with my select query. Let me know if i miss anything! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand. You are querying for all the questions with `exam_id != 3`, but you do not want the question with `id=23`? Does not make sense, since the latter one fulfills the condition you gave in the where clause

Comment: since i have already added id = 23 in exam_id = 3, i dont want to display that question while adding more questions to exam_id = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it.....

All I needed to do was, to fire the query again for not to repeat the questions that are selected previously....

```
SELECT * FROM paper WHERE question = '$row['question']' AND exam_id = '3'
if($select)
{
    ************************* SHOW RESULT *********************
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but you can make a list with the ids of the questions that you don't want to see.

For example: exclude `ids` 23, 24, 25

```
SELECT * FROM paper WHERE exam_id != 3 AND id NOT IN (23, 24, 25)
```

Comment: ...or introduce a flag on the database which marks those you want to see and everything remains data-driven